# invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' in this simple function

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Here is the code:

```
bool Vehicle::checkID(std::string id)
{
    std::vector<int> digits;

    for (char c : id)
    {
        if(std::isdigit(c))
        {
            digits.push_back(atoi(c));
        }

        else
        {
            digits.push_back(int(c));
        }
    }
```

I don't know why he throws this error for "digits.push_back(atoi(c))".

I'm a very beginner, I know this will be not that difficult for you.

Comment: ```atoi()``` expects a char pointer and you're passing it ```c```, which is a char.

Comment: Instead, since you _know_ `c` is a digit from `'0'` to `'9'`, you can do this with `c - '0'`.

Comment: thanks, how could i do it if I want to usw atoi()?

Comment: @MichiAriovist -- What are you really trying to accomplish with your function?  It's called `checkID`, but what are you checking?  If the string is all digits?  If so, there are 1-liners in C++ that will do whatever your code is attempting to do.

Comment: You could do something like `const char s[] = { c, '\0' };` and then use `atoi(s)`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie id is a string, containing digits and letters. All of them should be written in a int vector, the digits as they are, the letters with their ASCII-Values.

Comment: @MichiAriovist Your function's return type of `bool` gives the impression that something is being checked, and if it passes, return `true`, if not `false`.  Otherwise if you're not returning anything, then you will invoke undefined behavior.  BTW, the 1-liner for your code (if you're interested) is: `std::transform(id.begin(), id.end(), std::back_inserter(digits),[](char c){return isdigit(c)?c-'0':c;});`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do:

```
atoi(c)
```

`atoi()` expects a `char *`. You probably want

```
digits.push_back(c - '0');
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `atoi()` takes a single `const char *` type as a parameter.

You're calling it with a `char` parameter. The compiler doesn't know how to convert from one to the other.

`atoi` actually wants a string as input, you can't call it with a single character. A string always needs a zero character as a terminator.

Comment: thats pretty funny, when it comes to the task, I should solve it with atoi(). Maybe i understood it completely wrong. Thanks!